# Single authorization server for multiple resource servers

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, identityserver4

I've implemented ASP.Net core **Authorization Server** using IdentityServer4 and ASP.Net Identity. Is it a good practice to authorize multiple **Resource Servers** through this single **Authorization Server**?

P.S Resource servers are not related to eachother and provide different services

Comment: I don't think this is a problem. You can use one Authorization Server to authorize users at multiple Resource Servers.

Comment: @Max but how can I handle users with same username from different APIs, in single user table?

Comment: @BehzadBahmanyar why would you depend on the username and not specific claims from those apis ... identity would only hold the login details that way right ... ?

Comment: @MuqeetKhan Great, but what should I insert into the "Username" field? Also can you provide the answer with gtreater detail. Thanks

Comment: @Behzad Bahmanyar I'm currently implementing the same scenario. I believe the implementation is to disassemble the users repository into single to serve for multiple applications. that is why users are not linked to clients. as long as your clients would be happy to share users across with single login, I don't see a reason for your question. Ex: Gmail login supports for various apps who are completely different. don't forget you are doing openId implementation.

Comment: @Jay thx for reply, the reason for the question is I wanted to implement single solid Authorization Server, so my current and future Resource Servers use this server for authentication. It's not Single Sign-In, but, I wanted to find  a way not to implement a authorization server for every resource server. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Behzad Bahmanyar, hmm make sense. Single auth server with single user repository for multiple apps.  with openId ?? If I'm not wrong in Identity server you can't link an user to client/Application !!!